# Django admin: How can I put my logo on the page instead of the site title?

Tags: django, django-admin

I created django project. It works fine and I can login to admin section of the site.

At the top of every page, django shows the "django administration". I know how to change it.
Now, I want to know how can I put my logo on the page instead of that title?

I read about block branding but I am confused and some solutions I tried did not work. Of course maybe it was my fault and they detailed too advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In settings file, do below in TEMPLATES:

change the `'DIRS': [],` to `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/')],`, and create the templates folder.

If your `STATICFILES_DIRS` is empty set it to:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

Now copy the `base_site.html` to `templates\admin`.

**base_site.html:**

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}

{% load staticfiles %}

{% block title %}{{ title }} | {{ site_title|default:_('Django site admin') }}{% endblock %}

{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name">
    <a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">
        <img src="{% static 'logoname.png' %}" height="40px" />
    </a>
</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
```

And your admin will look like this:

[image]

This is the way you can do

Comment: Thanks but has errors: staticfiles raises error.

Comment: Share settings.py file and template structure